# C# Saving RichTextBox text with formatting to a specific location without Dialog box

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I had recently posted about this but didn't find the appropriate solution, probably due to not giving the whole context of my program.

I have  two `Form`(s) and in one of the forms, I have a `RichTextBox`, in the same form, I have a method (public) which is used to save the rich text in that RichTextBox` automatically to a specific location which it takes as a parameter.

From the other form, I get the location and pass it to the method and the file is create (in the format of .rtf) in that location but the problem is that the file is empty i.e. there is no text at all in that file.

Can you please help me sort out this issue?

Code:

```
   public void SaveIt(string parser)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(parser);
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(parser);
        file.WriteLine(this.NotePad.Rtf);
        file.Close();
    }
```

I pass parser this : E:\Profiles\Muhammad Waqas\Data\BE\note1.Rtf

Comment: Can you post the code, which you are using to write to the file.

Comment: Sure:        public void SaveIt(string parser)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(parser);
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(parser);
            file.WriteLine(this.NotePad.Rtf);
            file.Close();
        }

I pass parser this : E:\Profiles\Muhammad Waqas\Data\BE\note1.Rtf

Comment: I have edited the post. Please review

Comment: your code seems to be fine, to me. Check the edited answer.

Comment: You can accept my answer if it solves your problem. It is considered a bad practice on SO, to not accept worthy answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `StreamWriter` use it like this:-

```
    using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(parser))
    {
          Sw.WriteLine(this.NotePad.Rtf) ; 
    }
```